# Division of decimal part of number only

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway to divide the decimal of a number instead of the whole number. Like if I have a number that is 3.99 I would want to divide only the decimal by 1.66667. I want to do this because 3.99 is supposed to equal 3 minutes 59 seconds, so I would rather have it read 3.59 instead of 3.99.

This is the code I have to return the time now, btw it is returning a time from a program that is telling you how much time till something is due. But is used as a full two decimal number format.

```
function GetDiff(dt) { 
    sMins = " Min";
    sHours = " Hours";
    sDays = " Days";
    sSecs = " Secs";

    if (Math.abs(DateDiff("s", now, dt)) < 86400) {
        if (Math.abs(DateDiff("s", now, dt)) <= 3600) {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs(
                     DateDiff("s", now, dt) / 60) * 100) / 100
                     ).toFixed(2) + sMins);
        }
        else
        {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs(
                     DateDiff("s", now, dt) / 3600) * 100) / 100
                     ).toFixed(2) + sHours);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return ((Math.floor(Math.abs(
                 DateDiff("s", now, dt) / 86400) * 100) / 100
                 ).toFixed(2) + sDays);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't think of any sane encoding in which 3.99 could represent 3 minutes and 59 seconds. Are you sure what you want to do makes sense?

Comment: @user2357112 I assume it means 3.99 minutes.

Comment: 3.99 minutes equal 3 minutes and 59 seconds I want it in the format of 3:59 min not 3.99 mine it is a timer countind down I want a time format not a number format!

Answer (score 1):

You get the minutes - 3, and 0.99 minutes
Just 0.99*60 to get the seconds
and append it to the minutes
return "3"+"."+"59" + sMins

But it is not recommended to display "." for this case....

Comment: So the code I have isn't always 3.99 minutes that was an example the script is pulling from a database telling when a test is due. How would I plug into my script a way to do this. if its over 60 minutes it goes into hours in which case I need 2.50 hours which is 2 gours 50 minutes not 2 and a half hours which is what it does now, same with minutes.

Comment: What do you get from the server? 3.99?
please list out your input and expected output?

Comment: the time till a test is due comes from the database so it could be anywhere from 1-59 minute, 1-23 hours and above 23.99 hours is days which is fine the way it is.

Comment: So is there anyway to just change the decimal format from 1-99 to 1-59 with the code I posted in the original question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about 3.99 minutes I would start by converting them to seconds (the unit we really care about). With the total number of seconds you can then divide by 60 and chop off any remainder using `Math.floor` to get the number of minutes. You can then floor the result of the total number of seconds modulus 60 to get the "remaining seconds".

```
var decimalMinutes = 3.99;

var totalSeconds = decimalMinutes * 60;
var totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
var remainingSeconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds % 60);

// Outputs 3:59
console.log(totalMinutes + ":" + remainingSeconds);

// Float of 3.59
console.log(parseFloat(totalMinutes + "." + remainingSeconds));

// Float of 3.59 without type juggling
console.log(totalMinutes + (remainingSeconds / 100));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyF7c/1/)

Comment: so 3.99 min was an example it could be anywhere from 1 to 59 minutes and 1 to 24 hours. Plus I need to know how to plug into my script any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it still in decimal minutes? i.e. 10 hours, 15 minutes, 30 seconds = 615.5 or is there another format that you haven't told us about?

Comment: well if you look at the script I posted it returns minutes hours and days, but I only need to change minutes and hours to a minute/ second format or a hour/minute format.

Comment: still working on this problem it is in decimal minutes if there are less that 60 minutes left on the time till the test is due it is a timer in a sense in decimal hours if less that 24 hours on the time

Comment: I can't understand what you're actually asking. The above code takes decimal minutes and shows you how to convert it to standard minutes and seconds. What functionality is missing?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `number % 1` to get the decimal portion of a number:

```
var number = 3.99;                
alert((number % 1) / 1.666667);         // result: 0.59399.....
alert(Math.floor((number % 1) * 60));   // result: 59
```

Comment: still working on this the number is a timer it is counting down. how do I implement to the script I have?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var number = 3.99,
    percentOfSeconds = number - Math.floor(number), // result: .99;
    seconds = Math.floor(percentOfSeconds * 60);    // result 59
```

This doesn't take into account for leading zeros and such through.

Comment: So how do I plug that into the script I have?

Comment: I'd start with cleaning up your code so it's easier to work with and read. For example making `round` function `Math.round(x * 100)/100`. This will remove repeated code and make it easier to read. Also, since you always control the order of the dates you don't need all of those `Math.abs`. After that, looking at minutes section. I'd get the difference in minutes set it to a variable without flooring it. Then you can apply my code and combine the result in the return value.

Comment: I have no idea how to do any of that. I barely was ably to get it to return time after decimal before it was only an integer. The only way I could get it to come up with time in a decimal format was adding math.floor to math.abs then dividing as I did. otherwise the .tofixed would only return .00 without any change.

Comment: While knowing how to do this manually is very useful, the alternative is to use a library like (Moment.js)[http://momentjs.com/]. You might have better luck using that in this case.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work on and off with the code I have with no luck, can you show me how to implement with the script I have?